# Linphone libraries

Tags: nullpointerexception, static-libraries, linphone

Linphone now provides an SDK with a .jar file and three folders with .so libs. 
How can I work with this files in eclipse? I have tried copying this files into a libs folder and adding jar dependency, but when I first use a libphone object in my code I get a null pointer exception. How can I fix this?

I'm using windows 7 64bits and windows 8

Thanks in advance

Comment: first off all switch to android studio for better support....@isaac then i hope u will get better support

Comment: Yes, I did that, and I manage to compile. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put linphone.jar in libs folder

```
ProjectRoot>app>libs>linphone.jar
```

Put all other folders containing .so files int

```
ProjectRoot>app>src>main>jniLibs
```

and also include these Permissions in your manifest file

```
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <!-- Needed to allow Linphone to install on tablets, since android.permission.CALL_PHONE implies android.hardware.telephony is required -->
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
        android:required="false" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <!-- Needed to allow Linphone to install on tablets, since android.permission.CAMERA implies android.hardware.camera and android.hardware.camera.autofocus are required -->
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <!-- Needed to store received images if the user wants to -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <!-- Needed to use our own Contact editor -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
    <!-- Needed to route the audio to the bluetooth headset if available -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />
    <!-- Needed to pre fill the wizard email field (only if enabled in custom settings) -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS" />
```

Now you have done your setup.

From here to start use linphone documentation

[Linphone's Java Wrapper Documentation](http://www.linphone.org/docs/liblinphone-javadoc/)

and for native support

[Liblinphone C API documentation](http://www.linphone.org/docs/liblinphone/modules.html)

To get started i will suggest you start by implementing `LinphoneCoreListener`